# Visa requirements for Macedonia for Schengen-zone Permanent Residents?

Tags: visas, schengen, macedonia

I'm an Indian studying in Germany. I have a residence permit for Germany with which I can travel in the schengen area. Macedonia is not in the schengen area. However people with schengen visa can enter Macedonia for 15 days without visa. Is my German residence permit enough or do I need a seperate visa for Macedonia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was searching on the internet and I found this  [document](http://www.missions.gov.mk/PortalMissions/media/Consular-Documents-EN/Visa-Regime-eng-10-04-2013.doc)  from the Embassy of Macedonia, Berlin [website](http://www.missions.gov.mk/berlin/consular-information/information-for-foreign-citizens/http://www.missions.gov.mk/berlin/consular-information/information-for-foreign-citizens/?lang=en-GB)

In this document, it is mentioned that,

> Any foreign national, holder of valid travel document of a third country, who is required to have visa for entry in the Republic of Macedonia, may enter the territory of the Republic of Macedonia without having to acquire Macedonian visa, if  the foreigner has a permanent residence in EU or Schengen member state

This confirms that you can enter Macedonia without having a Macedonian visa if you have a valid passport and a **permanent** EU Residence Permit.

**Note:**
The residence permit that you have must be **permanent**.

What is a **Permanent residence permit**?
A permanent residence permit is an EU residence permit with unlimited validity. If you have an expiry on your residence permit, then it is not a permanent residence permit and it is not sufficient.

Comment: [2022-02-09: Visa requirements for entering the Republic of North Macedonia - Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.gov.mk/en/page/432/visa-requirements-for-entering-the-republic-of-north-macedonia): *Third-country nationals with **temporary [permanent] residence [multiple-entry Schengen visa (type C)]** in an EU Member State or a country signatory of the Schengen Agreement may stay no longer than 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry into the territory of the Republic of North Macedonia as long as the total length of stay does not exceed 90 days in any 180-day period*.

Answer (score 5):

I called the Macedonian embassy and told them that I am student here in Germany from India. "I have a schengen visa," I said. "Can I enter Macedonia with my current visa?"

And the embassy said yes. I along with my friend went to Skopje, Macedonia. We were stopped at the airport and sent back to Germany in the very first flight. As a gift, we got an entry rejection stamp on the passport. And I don't have any written proof. I can just say: Go and get a visa.

Answer (score 0):

Citizens of the following countries are not required to have entry visa for the Republic of Macedonia:

...

**Third countries with multiple entry short stay Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of Macedonia.**

*may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.*

[Source](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php/en/for-foreign-nationals/information-on-visa-entry-to-the-republic-of-macedonia/entry-in-the-republic-of-macedonia-for-schengen-visa-holders)

Answer (score 0):

those who want to travel to Macedonia with just an EU-ID card!

I want to share my own experience so everyone else who is considering travelling to Macedonia can go safely there and avoid flight cancellation. This was a costly lesson for me.

I'm a native Finn and so on also a permanent resident of the EU area. I booked a flight from Turku (Fi) to Skopje (N-Ma) on Wizzair Flight. Before the travel, I did a very comprehensive study and searched for information on web about needed travel documents to North Macedonia.

I had controversial information about CAN I TRAVEL TO MACEDONIA WITH JUST MY EU (FINNISH) ID-CARD? I didn't have a passport at the time so I wanted to be 100% sure that I can travel there with just my ID card. I was on that belief that as EU-Citizen I can travel there with just an ID card.

To be sure, I ask the Finnish embassy in Belgrad about this: The answer was yes, you can travel with an ID card. The same information was told on the Macedonian government website.

Finally, after I had a green light on my travel documents I entered Turku airport and the worst possible scenario happened: my journey stops at the check-in counter.

The wizzair clerk insisted that I need to have a passport and I try to ask if so, why I was given information at the Finnish embassy that I can travel with just ID-card. Why also the Macedonian government website told the same? Clerks were very reluctant to give me the right answer, I had comments like "We have had this same situation sooo many times. You need to have a passport to enter Macedonia".

That was the closure of my travel. So sad, I haven't had an opportunity to travel outside of Finland in 10 years.

In the end, I sent emails to the embassy why are you giving me false information? The reply was that those check-in clerks did a mistake, you should have the right to enter Macedonia!

I wasmore pissed off when I heard that so I made more queries to Turku airport (Finnavia) and Wizzair. Wizzair didn't refund me anything (even though I had wizzair's own cancellation insurance) and Finnavia denayed anything wrongdoing and refunds for me!

My point of sharing this is:
TRAVELLERS FROM OTHER EU COUNTRIES, PLEASE BRING YOUR OWN PASSPORTS IF YOU WANT TO TRAVEL TO MACEDONIA! Legislation might be different in each EU country but in the end, I had this closure: Finnavia told me that MACEDONIAN GOVERNMENT ALLOWS YOU TO TRAVEL THERE WITH JUST YOUR EU ID CARD HOWEVER the EU DOES NOT ALLOW YOU TO CROSS SCHENGEN BORDER WITHOUT PASSPORT! Since Macedonia is not an EU member state or the Schengen country.

I hope my example can save someone's journey, please tell me if someone else here had travelled to Macedonia with just ID card or if someone has something to add up, thank you! it is still really a puzzle to me why I was denied at the border since wizzair didn't required passport, only Finnish/Eu border officials.

Comment: Why do you believe that private airline knows the Macedonian requirements better than Ministry of Foreign Affairs of North Macedonia? [Visa requirements for entering the Republic of North Macedonia - Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.gov.mk/en/page/432/visa-requirements-for-entering-the-republic-of-north-macedonia): *Nationals of EU Member States and signatories of the Schengen Agreement DO NOT need a visa to enter the Republic of North Macedonia (and are eligible to enter the Republic of North Macedonia **with a valid national identity card**)*

Comment: Finnavia information is not corrct: [Passport and other travel documents – Finnish citizens' - Ministry for Foreign Affairs](https://um.fi/passport-and-other-travel-documents-finnish-citizens-): **Finnish citizens' passport and other travel documents**: *Passports and identity cards are travel documents. ; Finnish citizens travelling to the EU countries and to certain other European countries can use an identity card as their travel document instead of a passport.*

Comment: As far as I know the Finnish law requires you to have a passport with you when you are leaving the country unless you are traveling to a certain list of countries that doesn't include North Macedonia. As far as Macedonian officials are concerned they would let you in, but due to this weird Finnish law they do not let you leave the country without a passport. On the other hand if you were to travel to Germany first and from there to Macedonia you would be allowed.

Comment: @LassiUosukainen North Macedonia is, indeed, not listed here: [How to use the identity card - Police (of Finland) - Using the identity card as a travel document](https://poliisi.fi/en/how-to-use-the-identity-card)

Comment: Thank you, Lassi - Kiitos Lassi for this information! As I say, laws in different EU countries may vary and I didn't believe what the private airline said about travel documents; I ask the issue of traveling with an ID Card a Finnish ambassador who is doing a consulate job in Belgrad, Serbia. Finland does not have a consulate in North Makedonia so Belgrad ambassadors are also dealing with situations related to Makedonia. So as far as I know Lassi is right; It is ok on behalf of Makedonia to travel with an ID card but Finland does not allow travel to the non-Schengen country without a passport.

Comment: Mark: North Makedonia (previously known as the Former Yugoslavia Republic of Makedonia) is not an EU country or belongs to the Schengen area. You are right, any EU citizen can travel to other Eu-countries with only an ID card from the EU. Because I didn't have a chance to visit Makedonia, since I was not allowed to the flight, I traveled to Gdansk, Poland.  Since Poland is Eu-country it was totally OK for me to use ID card. there at the airport, hotel, and hospital, everywhere! You don't need a passport for anything if you are traveling inside the EU.

Comment: @robbani And?? It seems (based on the links that I provided) that it is **only** Finland that does not allow their citizens to to travel to North Macedonia with a Finish ID. Yet your answer states 'TRAVELLERS FROM OTHER EU COUNTRIES, PLEASE BRING YOUR OWN PASSPORTS IF YOU WANT TO TRAVEL TO MACEDONIA!'. Sorry, but you didn't inform **yourself** properly about Finish laws that **don't** apply to EU citizens in general.

Answer (score -2):

I was born in Macedonia and do not think you need a Visa to enter. But you have to report yourself and where you staying and pay around 50 cent per day

Comment: do you have any references?

Comment: Yes..but just because yu think so, I cannot take your word and enter the country.

Comment: This could be a great answer to a complex question.  Would you please provide a link to the Macedonian visitor rules?  Thanks!