# Travelling to Macedonia with German National visa

Tags: indian-citizens, long-stay-visas, macedonia

I am an Indian studying in Germany with German national visa i.e Visa Type D. I want to visit Macedonia. Is it possible with the national visa or do I need to apply for Macedonian visa while being in Germany (by applying for it in the Macedonian embassy in Germany)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a visa.

Indian citizens require a visa to enter Macedonia. There are exceptions if you hold a valid Schengen visa, but only if

- you're a permanent resident of a Schengen or EU country,
- you hold a multiple entry type C Schengen visa.

In these cases, you could enter for a stay up to 15 day without requiring a visa.

With a type D visa, you will probably not be considered a permanent resident, but you could of course just ask in the embassy.

Comment: Can I apply for the visa from Germany?

Comment: Don't know, maybe just give the embassy a call?

Comment: +1 becaues that's what the [official site says](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php/en/for-foreign-nationals/information-on-visa-entry-to-the-republic-of-macedonia/entry-in-the-republic-of-macedonia-for-schengen-visa-holders) but I find this requirement very unclear. There is no unified notion of “permanent stay” for third-country nationals in the Schengen area and I very much doubt Macedonian border guards are able to tell whether someone is a “permanent” resident or not (they probably don't care at all, in practice)

Comment: OTOH, if what is meant by permanent stay is “residence permit holder”, the distinction is easier to enforce but somewhat ill-advised, some countries have introduced 1-year type D visas that are effectively undistinguishable from the 1-year residence permit you can obtain after the first year. The only difference is that they are issued by a consulate and stamped in the passport instead of a plastic card. But residence permits do not have any permanent character…

Comment: There was a similar related question but not precisely what I have asked, but the OP answered his own question saying if the RP has an expiry date, it won't be counted as a permanent resident. Maybe that's what distinguishes permanent from not permanent? 

http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42823/visa-requirements-for-macedonia-for-schengen-zone-permanent-residents?rq=1