# Does a Vietnamese studying in France need a visa for a short visit to Macedonia?

Tags: visas, france, vietnamese-citizens, macedonia

I am a student in France with a 2-year residence permit (*titre de séjour*).
I have a Vietnamese passport.

Do I need visa to go to Macedonia for one week?

The website of Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Republic of Macedonia says:

> Entry in the Republic of Macedonia for Schengen Visa Holders
>
> Citizens of the following countries are not required to have entry visa for the Republic of Macedonia:
>
> 1. EU member countries and signatories of the Schengen Agreement have the right to enter the Republic of Macedonia with a valid ID card.
> 2. Third countries with permanent stay in an EU member country or signatory country of the Schengen Agreement may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.
> 3. Third countries with multiple entry short stay Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of Macedonia may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.

Comment: 1) Whether or not you need a visa will depend on you country of citizenship, not the country of residence. What is your country of citizenship? 2) Residence permit cards are not travel documents. To cross borders, you'll generally need a valid passport (though in some cases a national ID card might suffice, again depending on your citizenship).

Comment: @infrared That's not true or at least that's not what the question is about. I assume the OP will have a passport in any case but some EU residence permits exempt their holders of the visa requirement for Macedonia and some other non-EU Balkan countries so it does depend to some extent on the country of residence (for people who have a passport and require a visa in the first place).

Comment: We had a question about that and I am afraid we weren't able to get a definite answer. The English text does suggest your residence would **not** be enough, as strange as it seems.

Comment: Related/possibly duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42823/visa-requirements-for-macedonia-for-schengen-zone-permanent-residents

Answer (score 4):

I was in a very similar situation, yet my passport is Colombian.
I was allowed entrance into Macedonia and all the Balcans region (except Serbia) with my Schengen student visa (titre de sejour).

Comment: Was your Schengen student visa in the form of a passport sticker or a separate card?  Also, were you refused entry to Serbia, or is it an exception because you never tried to enter?

Comment: It was a sticker in my passport.
About Serbia i didn't actually tried, but i didn't because all the information from their website seemed to indicate that my Schengen visa wasn't enough to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter Macedonia with a PERMANENT Residence Permit only, which does not have expiry day on it. I was denied entry to Macedonia and that was they told me.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you have any additional information on the topic? What was your situation? Where can one find official references?